# проблема sharedpreferences в android 6

Tags: android

в андроид версии 4 sharedpreferences в методе onpause сохраняет данные а в андроид версии 6 в методе onpause данные не сохраняются в чем может быть дело
используя samsung gts-7390 на всех активити счетчик сохранялся при переходах а когда тестировал на смартфоне redmi счетчик на одной из активити сохраняться при переходах не хочет

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity  implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    public Toolbar toolbar;
    public TabLayout tabLayout;
    public ViewPager viewPager;
    public MyAdapter myAdapter;
    DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    NavigationView navigationView;
    ImageButton menuRight;
    Singleton singleton;
    ListView drawer_list;
    MyCustomListAdapter arrayAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(ru.newkod.dewbro.tablayout.R.layout.activity_main);

        singleton = Singleton.getInstance();

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(ru.newkod.dewbro.tablayout.R.id.toolbar_2);
        toolbar.setNavigationIcon(ru.newkod.dewbro.tablayout.R.drawable.gamburg);
        toolbar.setTitle("");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(ru.newkod.dewbro.tablayout.R.id.collapsingToolbar);

        drawer_list = (ListView) findViewById(ru.newkod.dewbro.tablayout.R.id.drawer_list);
        arrayAdapter = new MyCustomListAdapter(this,ru.newkod.dewbro.tablayout.R.layout.test,singleton.glist);
        drawer_list.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

        drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(ru.newkod.dewbro.tablayout.R.id.drawer);

        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.drawer_open,
                R.string.drawer_close);
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

      //  actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(ru.newkod.dewbro.tablayout.R.id.navigation);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(ru.newkod.dewbro.tablayout.R.id.tab_layout);
        myAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        myAdapter.addFragment(new Tab1());
        myAdapter.addFragment(new Tab2());

        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(ru.newkod.dewbro.tablayout.R.id.viewPager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(myAdapter);

        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.mipmap.bookz).setText("Меню");
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.mipmap.sale).setText("Акции");

        menuRight = (ImageButton) findViewById(ru.newkod.dewbro.tablayout.R.id.menuRight);

        singleton.finished =(TextView)findViewById(ru.newkod.dewbro.tablayout.R.id.finish);

        singleton.finished.setText("Итого: " + singleton.finish);

        singleton.dobavleno = (TextView)findViewById(ru.newkod.dewbro.tablayout.R.id.dobavleno);

        singleton.dobavleno.setText("+ " + singleton.dobav);
    }

    public void menuRight(View view) {
        if (drawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.END)) {
            drawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        } else {
            drawerLayout.openDrawer(GravityCompat.END);
        }
    }

    public void button_next(View view) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,Request.class);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        switch (id){
            case R.id.site:
                Intent intent_1 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse());
                startActivity(intent_1);
                break;
            case R.id.informat:
                Intent intent_2 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse());
                startActivity(intent_2);
                break;
            case R.id.call:
                Intent intent_3 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse());
                startActivity(intent_3);
                break;
            case R.id.document:
                Intent intent_4 = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse());
                startActivity(intent_4);
                break;
        }

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("first",MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor  = sharedPreferences.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(singleton.glist);
        editor.putString("first",json);
        editor.apply();

    }



}
```

Comment: Покажите код. Как вы проверяете, что данные не сохранились?

Comment: используя samsung gts-7390 на всех активити счетчик сохранялся при переходах а когда тестировал на смартфоне redmi счетчик на одной из активити сохраняться при переходах не хочет

Comment: в самом сохранении никакой проблемы нет, видимо проблема с синглтоном, который хранит данные. Сразу стоит сказать, что синглтон в андроид - плохая идея и по хорошему нужно от него избавится вовсе. Хранить в синглтоне виджеты это вообще неприемлемая практика и использовать такое ни в коем случае нельзя. на крайний случай использовать в его качестве наследника класа Application, но и там хранить виджеты - неприемлемо